# One-Factor Experiments with n Levels. Why Anova and Not Regression

Tags: regression, anova

Reviewing old notes. We have an experiment to see whether temperature levels affect output ( number of items.) So we consider 4 levels of temperature $100 , 150, 200, 250$ and we evalue for each, the number of items in the output. We repeat each experiment 6 times at each of the mentioned temperatures and each time we get the average output at each temperature. We analyze output using Anova. 
**Question** Why not just consider regressing output Y on temperature X using the averages as values instead of Anova? Is one way better than the other?

Comment: Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?

Comment: @JamesPhillips: Sorry James, this is from old class notes. If I can find them somewhere I will post them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with almost any choice of statistical procedures, it depends on your objectives and the data you have.

- If your purpose is to see whether there is a linear relationship between your independent variable and temperature, perhaps to predict future values of the IV based on temperatures in $[100, 250],$ then use simple linear regression.
- If you want to know the extent to which a 50-degree change in temperature (around 200 degrees) makes a significant difference in the IV, then use
  ANOVA.

Either way, it would be a good idea to check residuals to see if they
are nearly normal and have stable variance across temperatures.